# How to iterate and download multiple pdfs using selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I am a bit new to using selenium and Python.Below is the code that I am trying to run to download multiple files.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
cusip=['abc123','def456','ghi789']
for a in cusip:

    page=driver.get("http://mylink=" + str(a) + ".pdf")
    with open(a + '.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in page.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
```

Error that I receive is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shashi.singh/PycharmProjects/HiSSS/Selenium.py", line 13, in <module>
    for chunk in page.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iter_content'
```

Comment: Are you sure `driver.get("http://mylink=" + str(a) + ".pdf")` is returning anything?

Comment: It's not returning anything, it's a `NoneType`

Comment: Its a HTML page Chrisz.

Comment: Yes Colin, it is returning me the web url that basically has the pdf document for every item in the cusip list.

Comment: I can guarantee you that `page` is not an HTML page, it is a `NoneType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone..Below is the code that I am using and its working fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
cusip=['abc123','def456','ghi789']
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

tgt = "C:\\directory"  #target directory to download item
profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False, "name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
    "download.default_directory" : tgt}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",profile)
print(options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

for a in cusip:
    page=driver.get("http://mylink=" + str(a) + ".pdf") #iterate the item in cusip list

Print('Process completed Successfully')
```

The cusip is a list that I have to iterate and add it to the web page I need to download and hence you may modify it needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using selenium for this task.  If you have a list of urls, simply use [`urllib.request.urlretrive`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve):

```
In [5]: from urllib import request

In [6]: request.urlretrieve('https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.8470.pdf', r'C:\users\chris\test.pdf')
Out[6]: ('C:\\users\\chris\\test.pdf', <http.client.HTTPMessage at 0x59628d0>)
```

Just pass each url as the first argument, and the destination as the final argument.

Comment: Thanks Chriz.. Makes much sense if we already have the urls to use. One question though if we have a list like [(a.url,b.pdf),(c.url,d.pdf)]. How do you suggest to fetch the url using first value of list and then save it with a name picking the second value of list?